# Confused about input voltage on tablet

Tags: power-supply, voltage, battery-operated

The battery in my old Chuwi Hi9 Plus tablet started bulging and popped the screen out of its socket, so I had to dispose of it. The tablet still works fine when I power it from my bench supply (Rigol DP832), but I am confused about the voltages I am seeing/having to use.

The info on the battery looks like this:

[image]

The info shows standard Li-ion specs as far as I can tell, so to power the tablet from the bench supply I started out by setting it to output ~3.8 V (constant voltage mode). The tablet turns on and starts the boot process, but quickly turns off again after that. When I up the voltage to 5 V everything works with no problems.

Any idea why the tablet worked with the battery's ~3.8 V, but won't work for me now without the higher voltage which the battery should not have been able to deliver?

Comment: Did the current limit trigger on the bench supply? What is the current limit set to?

Comment: How much current is the tablet drawing on power up when you supply 3.8 V? How did you connect your power supply to the tablet (take a foto?)? Notice the battery label also says (Max Charge) 4.35V which probably means that this is the highest voltage it can be charged to. Have you tried intermediate voltages like 4.2V or 4.3V? 5V might not be safe for your tablet.

Comment: Theres a 3.2A limit on the supply which is what I set it to.
I am not sure if it reaches that as the values change very rapidly during the boot sequence. I have seen it reach ~2.4-2.6A, but it could potentially go higher.

I have tried the 4.35V, the battery info states this is the "max charge" limit. I can't finish the boot sequence on that either.

Comment: Where on the tablet did you connect your power supply?

Comment: Same place where the battery used to be connected, used the leftover cables from when i cut the battery loose. I left the yellow cable unattached as I found a few other posts online that said its not needed.